# Index of object in array found with match response[*]

Tags: karate

Is it possible to get the index value of a 
`* match response.Services[*] contains { "Service": "xyz"}`

I'm looking to reuse it later for more specific tests on the same Service object.
Theres reference to a `__loop` variable [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/calltable/kitten-create.feature) but I guess I don't really understand how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love your questions, you are certainly pushing Karate to the limits and I'm having to think hard to answer these as well :)

The `match` does not allow you to get the "found index" or even the "loop position" which come to think of it - may be actually relevant for a `match each` - but I digress.

This will take a few extra lines of code, and I really think you need to upgrade to 0.8.0. If it helps, I can confirm that there are no breaking changes (unless you use the stand-alone JAR).

The new `karate.forEach()` and `karate.match()` functions allow you to do very complex operations on arrays. Here are 2 examples:

```
Scenario: karate find index of first match (primitive)
    * def list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    * def searchFor = 3
    * def foundAt = []
    * def fun = function(x, i){ if (x == searchFor) foundAt.add(i) }
    * eval karate.forEach(list, fun)
    * match foundAt == [2]

Scenario: karate find index of first match (complex)
    * def list = [{ a: 1, b: 'x'}, { a: 2, b: 'y'}, { a: 3, b: 'z'}]
    * def searchFor = { a: 2, b: '#string'}
    * def foundAt = []
    * def fun = function(x, i){ if (karate.match(x, searchFor).pass) foundAt.add(i) }
    * eval karate.forEach(list, fun)
    * match foundAt == [1]
```

If you really can't upgrade, you can write a function to manually loop over the array and the above examples should get you a solution.

Comment: That seems like just the thing I'm looking for. Bear with me while I try it out next week. Thank you for the super fast support, btw.